# Unable to install scikit-image for python 2.7.12

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-image

I am not able to install `scikit-image` for python 2.7.12.

My first attempt to install `scikit-image` was by running the following command:

`$ pip install -U scikit-image`

However, I got an error saying:

> For Python 2.7, please install the 0.14.x Long Term Support using:
>   $ pip install 'scikit-image<0.15'

I ran the command above, but there's a dependency on python 3.5:

`$ pip install 'scikit-image<0.15'`

> Collecting scikit-image<0.15
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/04/f726af6b2e39a4dad0e5502670c4b33d5c915880a54a98aeb33b95150531/scikit_image-0.14.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
>   Collecting cloudpickle>=0.2.1 (from scikit-image<0.15)
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/fb/4f92f8c0f40a0d728b4f3d5ec5ff84353e705d8ff5e3e447620ea98b06bd/cloudpickle-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pillow>=4.3.0 (from scikit-image<0.15)
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/4b/5adc1109908266554fb978154c797c7d71aba43dd15508d8c1565648f6bc/Pillow-6.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
>   Collecting scipy>=0.17.0 (from scikit-image<0.15)
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/97/361c8c6ceb3eb765371a702ea873ff2fe112fa40073e7d2b8199db8eb56e/scipy-1.3.0.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-qQaiTX/scipy/setup.py", line 31, in 
>           raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.5 required.")
>       RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.

Does it make sense the fact that to install `scikit-image` with python 2.7 I have to install version <0.15... but that version needs python 3.5?

Comment: pip install scikit-image==0.14.1 try using this one

Comment: What is the output of `pip -V` ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pip install scikit-image==0.14.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in your error message:

```
Collecting scipy>=0.17.0 (from scikit-image<0.15)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/97/361c8c6ceb3eb765371a702ea873ff2fe112fa40073e7d2b8199db8eb56e/scipy-1.3.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/tmp/pip-build-qQaiTX/scipy/setup.py", line 31, in
raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.5 required.")
RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
```

You're getting the correct scikit-image (0.14.2), but now SciPy has received an update that is also incompatible with 2.7, so it itself raises an error (see that it is raised in file `.../scipy/setup.py`.) So you should try `python -m pip install scipy<1.3 scikit-image<0.15`.

You might have to do this for a few more cycles, as more and more packages are becoming Py3.5+ only.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version, `Scikit-image 0.15.0` doesn't exist for `Python 2`.

See the package's [pypi repository](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-image/#files) for some older version which has `Python 2` support. Also, check if you are using the correct `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

fitst:  `python2.7 -m pip install scipy==1.2.3`

then:  `python2.7 -m pip install PyWavelets==1.0.3`

then:  `python2.7 -m pip install scikit-image==0.14.5`

Answer (score -1):

If you have two versions of Python on the same machine, you could explicitly specify your version of pip and the package version to install:

```
#Find all versions available:
python2.7 -m pip install scikit-image==
#Then install your prefer/latest version from the list above. Example:
python2.7 -m pip install scikit-image==0.14.2 #Replace 0.14.2 with version from the above result
```

Worked for me with 2.7.15